# Multi-Threading TCP Echo Server In Python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

First of all ,I'm a beginner in python. I developed a simple TCP echo server that works nice but I decided to take it a step further and make it a multi-threading one. The code compiles but when I start connecting clients, it stops working. The problem seem to be in the calling of the parent constructor, but I can't figure it out. Here's the code I've developed so far...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket, threading

class workingthread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,client,ip,port):
        threading.Thread.__init___(self)
        self.client=client
        self.ip=ip
        self.port=port

    def run(self):
        data=client.recv(6000)
        print "Client Sent: ",data
        client.send(data)



tcpsocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcpsocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
tcpsocket.bind(("0.0.0.0",8000))
tcpsocket.listen(5)
(client,(ip,port))=tcpsocket.accept()

newthread= workingthread(client,ip,port)
newthread.start()
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one `_` too much in `Thread.__init___(self)`